# Performance of sqlite's aggregate functions max and min on integer primary key

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

I am using aggregate functions to get the max and min values from my primary key column, which is an integer, like so:

```
SELECT MAX(primary_key_column) FROM my_table  
SELECT MIN(primary_key_column) FROM my_table
```

I cannot find any documentation that clearly states how this will perform as the number of rows increases. Should I expect it go be fast due to the fact that there is an index for this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#minmax) clearly states that these queries

> will be optimized to run in logarithmic time assuming appropriate indices exist.